# Django Rest Framework Token Authentication with Postman

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I am trying to use **Postman** to test my DRF end-point, but I always get an `Authentication credentials were not provided.` error. The end-point works properly, but I haven't found how to send the request from **Postman**.

I am able to get the token for the user:

[image]

But I always get the error when I try to use the token to send a request:

[image]

I set the **Authorization Type** to `Inherit auth from parent`.

This is the code for the view:

```
class AlbumViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = proxies.AlbumProxy.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AlbumSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name', 'description', 'company__name')
    filter_fields = ('code', 'company')

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return []

        return super(AlbumViewSet, self).get_permissions()

    def retrieve(self, request, pk):
        password = request.query_params.get('password', None)

        try:
            instance = proxies.AlbumProxy.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except:
            return Response({'success': False, 'code': 1})

        if instance.access_code != password and password != settings.MASTER_KEY:
            return Response({'success': False, 'code': 2})

        instance_to_return = serializers.AlbumSerializer(instance=instance, context={'request': request}).data
        instance_to_return.pop('access_code')
        instance_to_return['success'] = True

        return Response(instance_to_return)
```

This is my `REST_FRAMEWORK` constant from `settings`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20,
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.metadata.SimpleMetadata'
}
```

Comment: ""I set the Authorization Type to Inherit auth from parent."" Change it to **No Auth** in POSTMAN

Comment: @JPG I get the same error

Comment: I found that it is the remote server with Apache that returns the error. Localhost returns success to Postman request.

Comment: what HTTP-server is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you use Apache you need to:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

add it to your `httpd.conf`

More details [there](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIPassAuthorization.html).

Comment: In Ubuntu, the file to modify is `apache2.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing `Token` to `Bearer` in the request body.

So, it should look like:

`Bearer <token>`

Answer (score -1):

Add in Headers:

Cookie sessionid={token}

[image]